# Show that $\langle G^+\rangle=G$ in a directed group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Lemma 2.1.8 of Glass' Partially Ordered Groups states:

> $G$ is a directed group if and only if $\langle G^+\rangle=G$ (where $G^+=\{x:x\geq1\}$)

This doesn't make any sense to me. For example, $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is a directed group (every two elements have an upper and lower bound) so the lemma implies that you can add some number of positive integers together to create a negative integer, which clearly isn't true.

Is he using some weird definition of $\langle \cdot \rangle$ (e.g. where the inverses of elements are included)? What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a group $G$ and a subset $S$ of $G$, $\langle S\rangle$ is (typically) defined to be the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ (*i.e.*: the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $S$). Thus, inverses are included.

Comment: Glass says: "If $A$ is a subset of a group $G$, we denote by $\langle A \rangle$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by $A$." Does "generated by $A$" typically mean "generated by $A$ and its inverses"?

Comment: Well, how does Glass define "generated by" in this context? Let me give you another example: When we talk about the subspace of a vector space being "generated by" a set of vectors, we don't mean the set of all sums achievable from those vectors with repetition allowed--rather, we mean the smallest subspace containing each of those vectors. It's the same idea here (unless Glass defines it differently).